# How does a device get mounted via the Unity Launcher

Tags: mount, hard-drive, fstab

When I click on a hard drive in the launcher, how does it know what parameters to apply to the mounted unit since the device is not shown or added in `/etc/fstab`. How can I add additional parameters to it so that, when I click on it, it mounts the device with the parameters I added.

Point in case, I want to add the `relatime` parameter to a HDD. This HDD is not in `fstab` but if I click on it in the launcher and then run `mount` I get this:

`/dev/sdb1 on /media/cyrex/xtreme type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)`

So how did it know to have this parameters `rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2` to this HDD and how can I add my parameters to this list (Without replacing the list, just adding to it).

Doing a `cat /proc/mounts |grep /media/cyrex` brings me the following:

```
/dev/sdb1 /media/cyrex/xtreme ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered 0 0    
/dev/sdc1 /media/cyrex/stuff ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/sdd1 /media/cyrex/titan ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
```

So for what I can tell, the parameters `rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered 0 0` are the default for this hard drives. So how can I add an additional parameter to this list or tell the system that when it loads, for example, `/dev/sdc1` it adds another parameter to it.